# how to pass xml results to core data object

Tags: iphone, xml, ios, caching, core-data

How do you pass a list of words that are in xml format to a "core data" database?

And from that, each time your application loads how do you check to see if that database is up to date?

Comment: I think you need to give some more details of what you are doing. The question is a bit vague. I.e. do you want to serialise to a core data database? Or do you want to process in some other way. What sort of core data back end are you using? and what do you mean by "up to date"? with what?

Comment: You learn how to create and manage objects in Core Data first, and **then** you start thinking about parsing XML into your model.

Comment: there is a list of manufactures I am accessing from a server that is in xml format, I want to download that that list and parse it to a core data sqlite database, that will act as a cache each time the app is opened there after. Then I would like to know whats the best way of checking if the new data in my sqlite database is up to date or note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to parse the incoming XML as string. If you are on a mac use NSXMLDocument... try something like this:

```
NSString *yourXML = @""; // replace with your xml as nsstring

NSError *error;
    NSXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:yourXML options:0 error:&error];
    if (error) NSLog(@"Error parsing xml: %@", [error description]);
```

And then you could parse every item you are interested in using an XPath query like this:

```
NSArray *items = [xmlDoc nodesForXPath:@"//yourItem" error:&error];
```

And then you could likewise loop every single item for its properties in xml format.

Then fetch an item according to one or more key properties you have in your xml and check if they are already there.

I suggest you take a look at this post http://objectivesheep.com/archive/core-data-active-record-sheepdata/ for an easier way to manage your core data objects. In that case you would simply have something like:

```
if ([YourManagedObject checkIfEntityExistsWhereProperty:@"yourKeyProperty" equalsValue:keyValueFromXML]) ....
```

Hope this helps.